# php on duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having trouble trying to get the following to work:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO member_data (member_id, name, address, telephone, mobile) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE member_data SET name = ?, address = ?, telephone = ?, mobile = ? WHERE member_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss', $_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['new_name'], $_POST['new_address'], $_POST['new_telephone'], $_POST['new_mobile'], $_POST['new_name'], $_POST['new_address'], $_POST['new_telephone'], $_POST['new_mobile'], $_SESSION['user_id']); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

It doesn't seem to be able to update or insert any values.

I'm sure I've done something wrong, but I've searched and haven't found anything relevant to my issue. Is this the right approach?

EDIT: Working code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO member_data (member_id, name, address, telephone, mobile) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = ?, address = ?, telephone = ?, mobile = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['new_name'], $_POST['new_address'], $_POST['new_telephone'], $_POST['new_mobile'], $_POST['new_name'], $_POST['new_address'], $_POST['new_telephone'], $_POST['new_mobile']);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to update or insert any values to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure about that `WHERE` statement at the end of query... try to remove it...

Comment: Removed it, didn't help.

Comment: And remove this `member_data SET` and also you probably have to replace `?` in ON DUPLICATE KEY statement by `VALUES(name)` and so on..